# Vba find duplicates and copy if none found

Tags: vba, excel, find

I'm trying to add a vba code that looks in a column on sheet YTDFigures and sees if there is a duplicate in sheet EeeDetails. If there isn't then I want to copy the YTDFigures data and paste in a new sheet.
The code I've tried gets an error `run time error 91` on the line `FinName = Worksheets("EeeDetails").Range("A:A").Find(What:=SearchName, LookIn:=xlValues)` I thought this would work as if a match isn't found the `.Find` function returns nothing.

```
Sub CheckMatch()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim SearchName As Range, SearchNames As Range
    Dim Usdrws As Long
    Dim row As Integer

    Usdrws = Worksheets("YTDFigures").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Set SearchNames = Worksheets("YTDFigures").Range("A2:A" & Usdrws)

        For Each SearchName In SearchNames
        row = Split(SearchName.Address, "$")(2)
        FinName = Worksheets("EeeDetails").Range("A:A").Find(What:=SearchName, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If FinName Is Nothing Then
                Range("A" & row & ":S" & row).Copy

                LastRow = Worksheets("Errors").Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1

                Worksheets("Errors").Activate
                Range("A" & LastRow).Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial
                Worksheets("EeeDetails").Activate
            End If
        Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I would recommend that you don't use Name as a variable, this is a reserved word in VBA, try changing Name to something like SearchName and then post the error you get if any...

Comment: Hi Xabier, I'm getting the same error as above having changed the names. But thanks I will make sure not to use Name as a variable again

Comment: Try `Set FinName = ...`

Comment: Hi BruceWayne, still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: @jufg I think you didn't understand what Bruce tried to mention, it should read as `Set FindName` you need to add the word `Set` before the FindName...

Comment: Oh yeah, what can I say, it's been a long day!! That's working perfectly now, thanks Xabier and BruceWayne

Answer (score 0):

You can place the raw data into an array, place the array on a temporary sheet, remove the duplicates, copy the data, then delete the temp sheet.

See below:

```
Sub CheckMatch()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet, tRows As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set RngA = ws.UsedRange.Columns("A")

    tRows = ws.Rows(ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Dim valA As Variant
    valA = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(tRows, 1)).Value

    Dim tempWs As Worksheet
    Set tempWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    tempWs.Name = "Temp1"

    With tempWs
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(tRows, 1)) = valA
        With .UsedRange.Columns("A")
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
            .Copy
        End With
    End With

    ' Do what you need to do with your copied data

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    tempWs.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Edit:**
I just tested this with sample data of over 10k rows, and it works in less than a half a second. It's very fast.